# Mapnik renderd on Linux cant load plugin library when running

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

I'm trying to run mod_tiles renderd but I have problems with plugins:
Problem loading plugin library: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/input/sqlite.input (dlopen failed - plugin likely has an unsatisfied dependency or incompatible ABI)
Problem loading plugin library: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/input/raster.input (dlopen failed - plugin likely has an unsatisfied dependency or incompatible ABI)
Problem loading plugin library: /usr/local/lib/mapnik/input/shape.input (dlopen failed - plugin likely has an unsatisfied dependency or incompatible ABI)

I use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit machine, mapnik-2.0.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with mapnik version.
Installed Mapnik again versus las mod_tiles version and it works.
Thanks!